# Wordpress Contact form 7: can I send 3 different emails?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a contact form where people register his friend. The form sends the information to me and thank you email to user which register his friend , but I need send one more email to his friend with a different text . Is that possible with contact form 7 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contact Form 7 has a `wpcf7_mail_sent` hook for this.

```
// ...in functions.php
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', function ($cf7) {
    // Run code after the email has been sent
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Since CF7 still doesn't do this itself, I wrote a basic plugin for it ([More Mails for CF7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/more-mails-for-cf7/)). The crux of it is using CF7's hooks and functions to do most of the work for you:

1. Add another mail property (if it doesn't exist) with the filter hook `wpcf7_contact_form_properties`
2. Add another mail form section with the `wpcf7_editor_panels` filter hook.
3. Sanitise the incoming mail form data and assign it as a property of the form object in the `wpcf7_save_contact_form` action hook.
4. Allow it to be sent with the `wpcf7_additional_mail` filter hook.

It's not hard, each step is quite small. The relevant code is [here](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/more-mails-for-cf7/trunk/more-mails-for-cf7.php), but you don't have to use any of the parts that create a settings page if you're happy setting a static number of extra mail messages in your code.